# Write Robocopy batch output to a text file trouble

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, logging, robocopy

I want to write the output of a Robocopy command into a text file that I can review to see which files were copied and so forth.

---

**I tried these commands...**

```
robocopy drive:\ destination:\ /e /v>log.txt
robocopy drive:\ destination:\ /e /v /l>log.txt
```

but none of them worked.

Furthermore, I also tried both commands with `>>log.txt` instead of `>log.txt` using both forms of redirection in that syntax variation but still didn't work.

Comment: You may need to redirect error messages, which can be done using `2>` instead of (or in addition to) the plain `>`.

Answer (score 2):

## Having Robocopy command output to file trouble. . .

Use the below command syntax instead since Robocopy has its own logging options just use those

```
ROBOCOPY "drive:\" "destination:\" *.* /E /V /NP /R:5 /LOG+:log.txt /TS /FP
```

> **Note:** `/LOG+:file` in particular.

Use `Robocopy /?` and/or the below resource link to see all the available options.

> ```
> /E         :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
> /V         :: produce Verbose output, showing skipped files
> /NP        :: No Progress - don't display % copied.
> /R:n       :: number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million.
> /LOG+:file :: output status to LOG file (append to existing log).
> /TS        :: include source file Time Stamps in the output.
> /FP        :: include Full Pathname of files in the output.
> ```

---

### Supporting Resource

- [Robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)